# issue in redux, once create a redux application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
//created action.js,rootReducer called everything in index.js but having issue on same.. 

//getting issue:-

Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Home)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(Home) in connect options.
```

//added rootReducer.js:-

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
export default combineReducers({     
})
```

//added action.js:-

```
    export const helloRedux= () =>(dispatch:any)=>{
        alert("Heloo Redux")
    }
```

//added index.js:-

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


    import { Provider} from 'react-redux';
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
    import  ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
    import  rootReducer from './rootReducer';
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))


    const MyAppWithStore = () => (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    );

    ReactDOM.render(<MyAppWithStore />, document.getElementById('root'));
    serviceWorker.unregister();
```

//added home.js:-

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { connect } from 'react-redux'
    import { helloRedux } from '../services/action'
     class Home extends Component {
        render() {
            console.log(this.props)
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>home Component</h1>
                    <button onClick = {() => this.props.helloRedux()}>Click Me</button>
                    {/* <button onClick = {() => this.helloRedux()}>Click Me</button> */}
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    const MapDispachToProps = dispach =>({
        helloRedux:()=> dispach(helloRedux())
    })

    const mapStateToProps= state=> {
        {

        }
    }
    const HomeCom =connect(
        mapStateToProps, 
        MapDispachToProps
        )(Home)
    export default HomeCom;


  //app.js

import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Home  from './component/home'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <header className="App-header">
        {/* <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" /> */}
        <Home />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;



//created action.js,rootReducer called everything in index.js but having issue on same.. 

//getting issue:-

Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Home)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(Home) in connect options.
```

Comment: ```const mapStateToProps= state=> {
        {

        }
    }``` This snippet of code is wrong because lacks of return statement. By the way, it isn't useful because you don't insert anything inside.

Comment: Will you please post the code of app.js also?

Comment: added app.js...

Comment: You haven't posted your "real" code. Take a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ugupmk) fork it and update it if you need to to demonstrate your actual issue.